# Does Kotlin optmize the creation of lambdas in the JVM?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, jvm

I have a code that looks like the following:

```
infix fun <T> Option<T>.valueIs(value : T): Pair<() -> Boolean,Set<Node>> {
    val function = {this.selectedValue == value}
    val parents = setOf(this)
    return Pair(function, parents)
}
```

My question is if Kotlin will always create an anonymous object in `val function = {this.selectedValue == value}` in the JVM every time that this extension function is called or if it has some sort of optimization to reuse it if `this` and `value` are the same.

Comment: Your realize `function` holds a hard reference to `value` so reusing it would cause issues right?

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin, like Java, can avoid creating a new object each time if your lambda doesn't access (also called "capture") variables declared outside it (including `this`); `{this.selectedValue == value}` captures `this` and `value`, so it doesn't.

You could imagine some cache mapping captured variables to lambda instances, so it's effectively

```
private val lambdas = mutableMapOf<Any, () -> Boolean>()

infix fun <T> Option<T>.valueIs(value : T): Pair<() -> Boolean,Set<Node>> {
    val function = lambdas.getOrUpdate(Pair(this, value)) {this.selectedValue == value}
    val parents = setOf(this)
    return Pair(function, parents)
}
```

but:

1. it prevents lambdas from being garbage-collected *just in case* you'll call the method with the same `this` and `value` later (could be fixed by using `WeakHashMap`);
2. it's non-trivial overhead even neglecting that;
3. it requires any captured values to have well-behaved `hashCode` and `equals`. Ok, they should have them anyway, but just imagine problems from debugging this if they don't!

Kotlin has another very important way to avoid creating objects for lambdas: passing them as arguments to [`inline` functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html). Of course it isn't applicable when you want to put your lambda into a data structure (even one as simple as `Pair`) or just return it.

Comment: You could mention the easier workaround, marking the higher order function `inline` which would eliminate the function allocation at the expense of enlarging the compiled classes that call it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I was going to when writing the answer, but apparently forgot, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Decompiling the bytecode:

```
   @NotNull
   public static final Pair valueIs(@NotNull final Option $this$valueIs, final Object value) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull($this$valueIs, "$this$valueIs");
      Function0 function = (Function0)(new Function0() {
         // $FF: synthetic method
         // $FF: bridge method
         public Object invoke() {
            return this.invoke();
         }

         public final boolean invoke() {
            return Intrinsics.areEqual($this$valueIs.getSelectedValue(), value);
         }
      });
      Set parents = SetsKt.setOf($this$valueIs);
      return new Pair(function, parents);
   }
```

As we can see, the lambda creates a new object `Function0` every time this function is called.
So, every time this function is called. It seems that a new object will be created.